# Render to texture in Delphi using OpenGL

Tags: delphi, opengl, windows-7, 2d, render-to-texture

I am making simple GUI for my not-so-simple OpenGL game. Since there is a big menu with a lot of control count, I grouped the controls and put them into different windows that could be accessed via buttons in the main menu. So now I would like to replace the buttons with clickable thumbnails of each window and that is why I need to render the GUI to texture.

Currently I have computer with Windows 7 with Geforce 210 video card that supports OpenGL up to 3.3.0 version (but I don't care what version I will use). I have 'dglOpenGL.pas' library for Delphi. I would like  to render those windows with controls to textures but because I am n00b at such things, I can't do it (I tried tutorials for C#, but with no working results so far). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are making a 2D GUI and don't care about speed, why not use plain GDI?

Comment: @Andreaas Rejband: good argument, but my GUI is for OpenGL game :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render-to-texture in OpenGL involves creating a framebuffer object (FBO) and attaching it to a texture.  Have a look at [the documentation for framebuffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) for a basic overview.

The general workflow is like this:

- Create a framebuffer object with [glGenFramebuffers](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenFramebuffers.xml)
- Activate the framebuffer with [glBindFramebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindFramebuffer.xml)
- Attach the framebuffer to the texture you want to render to with [glFramebufferTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture.xml)
- Call [glCheckFramebufferStatus](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) to ensure that it worked.
- Set the viewport to match the dimensions of the texture you're rendering to.  (This generally involves calling glViewport and glOrtho, which I'm sure you're already familiar with so I won't link them here.)
- Do your rendering.
- When you're done, deactivate the FBO (call glBindFramebuffer again and pass 0 as the FBO ID value) and reset your viewport.
- Whatever you've rendered should now be there in the texture.

Comment: 'glCheckFramebufferStatus' returns 0 :(

Comment: @Roberts: According to the documentation, that means an error of some sort occurred.  Try calling `glGetError` and see if the result helps any.  If not, post the code you're trying to use on here as a new question (including the error results) and see if one of us can help out.